# Fourier transform of $\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am required to find the Fourier transform of the following function:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x}$$

Where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

---

This is what I've tried, but I'm not quite sure:

The Fourier transform (denoted by $\mathcal{F}(s)$) is given by:

$$\mathcal{F}(s) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(sx) dx \tag{1}$$

Where $f(x) = \frac{e^{-ax}}{x}$.

Differentiating with respect to $s$ on both sides and simplifying:

$$\frac{d}{ds}(\mathcal{F}(s)) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x}.\sin(sx)\right) dx$$

$$=\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\cos(sx)dx$$

This is a standard integral; we get:

$$\frac{d}{ds}(\mathcal{F}(s)) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\dfrac{a}{a^2+s^2}$$

Now,

$$\mathcal{F}(s) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\int \dfrac{a}{a^2+s^2} ds$$

Which is also a standard integral. The result is

$$\mathcal{F}(s) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{s}{a}\right) + C \tag{2}$$

Also, from $(1)$, we know that $\mathcal{F}(0) = 0$. Using this in $(2)$ we get
$$C = 0$$

Therefore, the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(s)$ of the given function $f(x)$ is

$$\mathcal{F}(s) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}.\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{s}{a}\right) $$

---

Is my working correct?

I have a strong feeling that I'm missing something; I concede that I do not have a good understanding of Fourier transforms. Any and all corrections and/or tips are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f$ does not exist in a classical sense.

Comment: @copper.hat could you please explain your reasoning? I solved it the way I did because I came across this method on a different site. I'm also unsure whether or not I am supposed to repeat this by replacing $sin(sx)$ with $cos(sx)$ in equation $(1)$

Comment: Well, the classical transform requires that $f$ be integrable, and an extension is the Plancherel transform which requires $f$ be $L^2$. The next step would be in a distributional sense.

Comment: @copper.hat we can consider (sine-)Fourier transform for any function $f$ such that the integral $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \sin(\lambda x) dx$ converges (or exists in any sense). In this case this integral converges. In general, I saw extensions of such transformations, where it was demanded that the integral be at least Cesàro summable.

Comment: @jan : You're not using the values of $f(x)$ for $x < 0$ anywhere. How do you expect that to represent the Fourier transform of $e^{-ax}/x$?